# Create a reusable layout component with multiple columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, layout

I have a reusable layout component accepting `children` as props. This way I can separate the components needed for each page in a separate file as shown in the example below:

```js
// Layout.jsx

function Main({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Side({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

Layout.Main = Main;
Layout.Side = Side;

export default Layout;
```

```js
// Home.jsx

function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout.Main>
        foo
      </Layout.Main>

      <Layout.Side>
        bar
      </Layout.Side>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

This works pretty well, but now I want to add a component which is shown in all of the `Layout` pages. The problem is, this component is animated so when it's added to the `Layout` component, it will rerender everytime the page changes.

I want to keep my code between my pages separated but still want to use the `Layout` component and use the animated component. How can I do this?

---

```js
// Home.jsx

function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout.Main>
        {/* This component moves from x to y depending on the url */}
        <ComponentWithAnimation />

        <Home.mainColumn.components />
      </Layout.Main>

      <Layout.Side>
        <Home.sideColumn.components />
      </Layout.Side>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

```js
// Other.jsx

function Other() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Layout.Main>
        {/* This component moves from x to y depending on the url */}
        <ComponentWithAnimation />

        <Other.mainColumn.components />
      </Layout.Main>

      <Layout.Side>
        <Other.sideColumn.components />
      </Layout.Side>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Other;
```

In the example above, instead of having the `ComponentWithAnimation` animate to `y`, it starts immediately at `y`. I could add logic to add a starting position to the last location, but I was wondering if there's a solution using a layout.

Comment: _this component is animated so when it's added to the Layout component, it will rerender everytime the page changes_  Can you demonstrate that problem, please?

Comment: @Wyck: added an example.

Comment: I don't see anything that couldn't be done with some clever CSS and no rerendering.

Comment: @Wyck: do you mind to show me a simple example (with dummy data if needed) of how you would do it? I'd like the code to be as maintainable and readable as possible, i.e. `home` and `other` should both have the code for the main and side column independently.

Comment: `Home` and `Other` are literally identical code in your example, so I'd say it's not really a good example of what you're trying to accomplish.  What are you intending to be _different_ between the two components?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point. `Home` and `Other` is almost identical except for `foo` and `bar` needs to be replaced by the page specific components. So basically `Home` has it's own set of components in the place of `foo` and `bar` and `Other` has it's own set of components in the place of `foo` and `bar`. I've prefixed it in the example to make it visually easier to understand.

Comment: Ok, but in your example you have two **different** `ComponentWithAnimation` components (they will have different references).  So how do you intend to express that they are supposed to be the **same** component (i.e. not restart their animation)?  (In other words, how would you create a *different* component if you wanted one?) 
 Honestly, I'd just redesign so that the common components are in a common parent component and pass props for anything that needs to be different in the children.